# Google spreadsheet API not responding since July 29 EDT

Tags: google-sheets

I am using Googlespreadsheet API, it hangs for ever on this method:
spreadSheetEntry.getWorksheets();

It works before 12:00 pm, July 29 EDT, failed sometime around 13:00 pm

Code:

```
    String feedUrlStr = feedUrl.toString() + "?title-exact=false&title=" + URLEncoder.encode(query);
    feedUrl = new URL(feedUrlStr);
    this.SpreadSheetFeed = this.service.getFeed(feedUrl, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    this.SpreadSheets = this.SpreadSheetFeed.getEntries(); //it works here,can find spreadsheet.
```

it hangs when trying to get worksheets.

```
this.SpreadSheets.get(sheetindex).getWorksheets();//hangs on the function getWorksheets();
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include an [mcve], which is a) the desired behavior, b) the *specific problem or error* you're seeing and c) the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same thing when hitting the https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/key/private/full URL directly.

It is still documented here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?hl=en#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections - didn't see any sings that it would be deprecated...